# PHP getting a response from the server

Tags: php, response

I am a little bit confused with PHP. It's a simple question

I want to submit a form. For example:

```
<form name='formname' action='code.php' method="POST">
    <input name='inputname' type='text'/>
    <input type='submit'>
</form>
```

So, the server gets whatever is typed and for argument sake it adds `cool` to the end of the text and echos `$inputname.'cool text you got there';`

How do I get that response and use it in my javascript?

Comment: With a page reload or on the same page; ala ajax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your response would be in `code.php` or a page that `code.php` redirects to.

Basically, you submit the form, it loads code.php, any logic that the form inputs use go there and interact with the database, then you choose how to redirect the user from there.

If you want to see if the inputname form input is getting set, you can do this:

```
<?php
        if(isset($_POST["inputname"]))
        {
            $inputname = $_POST["inputname"];
            echo $inputname;
        }
        else
        {
            echo "inputname not set!";
        }
?>
```

To get it to be used in your javascript, one potential way of doing that is adding a variable to the url:

```
./mypage.php?input=yourinputname
```

Then, on your main page with the form (or whatever page you redirect to), you can use PHP to check to see if `$_GET['input']` exists, then echo it if you like.

Comment: The part that is really confusing me is that once i echo my results from the php form. i can send a text and then depending on what the text says i can use javascript. but i don't know how to get the response in a post method
-ps i love this website people are so helpful thank you all

Comment: In your post class code.php, do you have a line: `header("Location: otherpage.php");` ?
That is a line that redirects the user after posting the form. What you can do is add parameters to that redirect: `header("Location: otherpage.php?javascript=1");` then check in php `if($_GET['javascript'] == 1) ...`. Look up a tutorial on php postback if you are still having issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it on the new page - so the form is submitted, the browser goes to the PHP page specified in the form.. Then you'd have something like this..

```
<?php
$input = $_POST['input'] . 'Cool text you got there!';
?>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
var varName = '<?php echo $input ?>';
</script>
```

However, if you want AJAX style without jQuery - you'd use [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) to get the data from the PHP script directly into the webpage, by intercepting the event handler for the form.

Comment: It is a POST form, not a GET form.

Comment: Oops, My bad! Same rules apply though.